# Do we need the relativity tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we need the [relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity) tag? Most questions using it are generally because it's a popular science question and the OP doesn't know which to use **or** because the OP used it along with [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity) or [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity).

Why not get rid of it?

Comment: The recommended practice until now is explained in the corresponding wiki tags, i.e. the rel. tag is used for posts where *both* the GR and SR tag apply.

Comment: Please don't start retagging until consensus has been reached.

Comment: @Manishearth: Even for questions where the relevant tag (SR or GR) is already stated? Lie [tag:special-relativity], [tag:general-relativty], [tag:relativity]? ,

Comment: Doesn't matter, basically, if something is being discussed on meta, don't put unnecessary effort into implementing it until a decision has been reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have [103 questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brelativity%5D%20-%5Bspecial-relativity%5D%20-%5Bgeneral-relativity%5D%20is:question)  tagged with *only* [relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity)

We have [9 questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brelativity%5D+%5Bgeneral-relativity%5D+-%5Bspecial-relativity%5D++is%3Aquestion) tagged with [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity) and [relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity) but not [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity)

We have [16 questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brelativity%5D+%5Bspecial-relativity%5D+-%5Bgeneral-relativity%5D++is%3Aquestion) tagged with [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity) and [relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity) but not [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity)

We have [10 questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brelativity%5D%20%5Bgeneral-relativity%5D%20%5Bspecial-relativity%5D%20is:question) tagged with all three. I've noticed that most of our relativity questions are about general relativity

The best solution here is to go through the [118 questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brelativity%5D%20-%5Bgeneral-relativity%5D%20is:question) tagged [relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity) but not [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity), and look for ones without GR on them. Then merge.

I don't mind keeping the tag, either. FWIW it may be worth merging the SR and GR tags into [relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity), but that may lead to a broad tag.

Comment: The last option, merging everything into relativity , , isn't a good idea. GR questions are often very different from SR questions. And relativity is also a pretty vague tag. Like: Is Galilean Relativity also counted? Of course, someone can read the tag wiki, but the name should be more explanatory, in my opinion. , .  . . .  .

Comment: @Dimension10 I thought so too, I just wanted to throw it out there. A better idea is to merge relativity into one of the two sub-tags. (after some pre-merge retagging)

Answer (score 3):

I'd be fine with removing it. I've always been somewhat in favor of getting rid of this tag (just not enough to do anything about it), because posts which both [general-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity) and [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity) apply to can just be tagged with both of those, and otherwise we just use one or the other as appropriate.

The potentially difficult thing about this will be going through all the questions tagged [relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relativity) and sorting them out into GR or SR.